# Saving or downloading matplotlib plot images on Google Colaboratory

Tags: matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I am using matplotlib in Google Colaboratory and trying to save the plot images somewhere (either downloading locally or uploading to Google Drive). I'm currently displaying the image inline with:

```
plt.show()
```

Here's what I've attempted, although it only downloads a blank image:

```
import os    
local_download_path = os.path.expanduser('~/data')
plot_filepath = os.path.join(local_download_path, "plot.png")

plt.savefig(plot_filepath)

from google.colab import files
files.download(plot_filepath)
```

I've also tried using the Drive API to upload the plot image, but haven't had success there either.

Comment: Can you just right click and save image?

Comment: Yes, but I'm generating many plots.

Answer (score 10):

Did you make sure that you didn't show the plot before using `savefig()`? Here is a complete working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files

test = plt.figure()
plt.plot([[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3]])
plt.savefig('test.pdf')

files.download('test.pdf')
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it. I plt.show() before saving it which worked on my own computer but not on colab.

Comment: @lhhong same for me

Answer (score 5):

You need to show the plot and specify which plot to save. Otherwise, you're just saving a blank plot canvas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files

test = plt.figure()
plt.plot([[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3]])
plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
test.show()

test.savefig('samplefigure.png')
files.download('samplefigure.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want  high resolution image use this code:

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from google.colab import files

  image = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10), dpi= 200)
  image.savefig('myimage.png',  bbox_inches="tight")
  files.download('myimage.png')
```